# Google Sheets check if cell has border using script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add custom formatting to a report so that any brand that uses it, can change to their brand colours.

I currently have the cell colour changing but I only want those cells to change colour if they have a border. So it's using the border as an AND check.

Here is the current version which will change the cells if they match a colour. However, if they are changed to white and then you want to change to another colour, then the whole sheet changes colour. So I was considering how I can make a set of cell unique so the script only actions on those.

```
function colorReplace() {
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('SPREADSHEET_URL');
  var doc = spread.getSheetByName("DASHBOARD_NAME");
  var settings = spread.getSheetByName("Settings");

  // get all the existing active sheet background colours
  var cells = doc.getRange(1, 1, doc.getLastRow(), doc.getLastColumn()).getBackgrounds();
  var rows = cells.length;
  var cols = cells[0].length;

  var primary = doc.getRange('E2').getBackground(); // Get background of ref cell
  var primaryReplace = settings.getRange('B2').getValue(); // Get background from cell in settings
  var border = settings.getRange('B5').getValue(); // Get border colour from cell in settings

  //Logger.log(primary);
  //Logger.log(primaryReplace);

Boolean for those cells which have a border

  // iterate accross
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
      if (cells[i][j] == primary && cells[i][j] == check ){ 

// if cells equal cell colour and they have a border. Possibly could just change this to if cells have a border?

            cells[i][j] = primaryReplace; // Cell Colour Change
          }
        }
      }
      // update backgound colours
      doc.getRange(1, 1, doc.getLastRow(), doc.getLastColumn()).setBackgrounds(cells);
    }
```

Comment: I don’t see any get border commands in the range class

Comment: Perhaps you could set the numberformat to some unique string that will identify which cells get the color change. The numberformat can be a 2d array so it can be read via loop indices and set it back to what it was after changing colors

Comment: @cooper Thanks for the replies. I checked the documentation and could see a way to check for a border. Google slides has getFillColor for borders. I was possibly thinking of trying to add something unique like you mentioned but thought I'd  see if anyone has had luck targeting borders. I'll look to try format as you mentioned in the meantime.

Comment: You could also try setting the background color to some weird color just as easily.